# Which database operations have to be executed in background?

Tags: android, database, cursor, background-thread

Im a bit confused about which operations have to be executed in background thread:

```
Cursor curserU = myDataBase.rawQuery("some query");
startManagingCursor(curserU);
curserU.moveToFirst();
curserU.someFuctionWhichWillReturnData();
```

is it enough if only this line runs in background:

```
      Cursor curserU = myDataBase.rawQuery("some query");
```

or does everything have to beinbackground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting `rawQuery()` into background thread is enough. When you are passing `Cursor` into `SimpleCursorAdapter` for example, it operates on `Cursor` on `UI thread`. But consider using [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) as [startManagingCursor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startManagingCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29) is marked as deprecated.